# unresolved external symbol _NPN_MemAlloc referenced in function

Tags: c++, memory, npapi, xpcom

i develop extension for Chrome using XPCOM and i try communicate my dll with JS all fine ! but if i try return value ( string ) from my cpp code i have crash my browser ((( me need allocate memory through NPN_MemAlloc ! but i can't because my VC2008 show me subj error !

i include on my

```
stdafx.h 
npapi.h
npfunctions.h
npruntime.h
```

but not result

next i add

```
pragma comment(lib,"xpcom.lib");
```

and nothing ((( Link error (((

i search on web answer for my question - and NOTHING (((

how i can fix Link error ? 
i download Gecko-sdk1.9 from - mozila site and add settings to my progect

> include 
>   "C:\xulrunner-sdk\include";"C:\xulrunner-sdk\include\nspr";"C:\xulrunner-sdk\include\mozilla\plugins"

dll include in link settings

> "C:\xulrunner-sdk\lib"

any can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why `npapi.h` declares `NPN_MemAlloc`, however I looked at the source for Mozilla's test plugin and it actually has a definition for `NPN_MemAlloc`; all it does is call through the `memalloc` member of the `NPNetscapeFuncs*` parameter of your `NP_Initialize` method.